# Counting number of item types in a series in Python

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

I am getting values from an api call and it returns one json value/key pair as a string at a time. I need to count how many times items with a certain prefix (which encodes the type of the item)  occur:

Lets say I am getting 'abc123' as the 1st value

```
def getType(nodeName):
    nodeCount = 0
    if "abc" in nodeName:
        count = count + 1
        return "ABC", count
```

How do I retain this `nodeCount` value so that next time an item with prefix 'abc' comes in from the api call, the count can be incremented to 2.
Also, I need to create other counters to keep track of the count of other node types, such as 'xyz777'.

I tried to declare `nodeCount` as global variable but if I add "global count", that will defeat the purpose of retaining the count value for the next api call/iteration.

I am very new to python, so please let me know if there is any easy way.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) like this:

```
from collections import Counter

def getType(counter, nodeName):
    nodetype= nodeName.rstrip('0123456789')
    counter[nodetype] += 1
    return nodetype.upper(), counter[nodetype]


c= Counter()
for n in ['abc123', 'def789', 'ghijk11', 'def99', 'abc444']:
    nodetype, nodecount = getType(counter= c, nodeName= n)
    print('type {} \t: {}'.format(nodetype, nodecount))

print('summary:')
print(c)
```